# Why does my program asks for input twice?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I need to create a list and print it and next i want to return only even numbers.

Created two functions:
First_function -> returns original list
Second_function -> returns even numbers from original list

```
def creat_list():
    return [int(input("Number - ")) for i in range(int(input("Size - ")))]

l = creat_list()

def even_list():
    return [i for i in l if i % 2 == 0]

print("Original list", creat_list())
print("Even list: ", even_list())
```

My program works ok except the fact that it asks for input two times. I cannot really figure out why. I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Because you call `creat_list` again at the end?

Comment: so i should do : print("Original list", l)

Comment: Give it a go, does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

This will do what you want and use the return statement (which you aren't in the original code:

```
def creat_list():
    return [int(input("Number - ")) for i in range(int(input("Size - ")))]

def even_list(l):
    return [i for i in l if i % 2 == 0]

print("Original list")
l = creat_list()
print("Even list: ", even_list(l))
```

Comment: but in your code you can ocult the argument in the second function  (I think)